# React JS AWS Cognito error Logins don't match

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

I have a problem with log in. I always get this error: `Logins don't match. Please include at least one valid login for this identity or identity pool.`
I have a registered user and confirm him in my pool and everything looks ok.

i use [react-cognito](https://github.com/isotoma/react-cognito) and i think i have all implemented right (by [example](https://github.com/isotoma/react-cognito-example) ) and i have no idea how to fix this issue.
Can you help me? 
thank you

Answer (score 4):

This error for me was because I had previously logged in with a different user storing their JWT tokens in local storage, then logged in with a different user which confused things.

There seems to be a bug with the latest but now deprecated (non-AWSAmplify) version of the amazon-cognito-identity-js library where it doesn't clear the JWT tokens when you call its signout() method.  This can be fixed by manually clearing the keys from local storage.

Comment: yes adding `AWS.config.credentials.clearCachedId();` before `AWS.config.credentials.refresh` or `AWS.config.credentials.get` fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if we are using the same sdk, but I was able to solve the same problem adding a new parameter while creating credentials, it is indeed related to the cache.

You'll find more information in this issue https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/609

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess the root cause without thoroughly testing & debugging the code but I have seen errors like this. This happens when an incorrect Id token is used in the Login map for an Identity Pool. Generally, this happens because of Caching after a user has been signed out; using Clear() or similar methods which clear cached values resolves this.

But again, without reviewing your code, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use aws-amplify for federated identities. Take a look [federated identities on aws-amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/authentication_guide.html#federated-identities-social-sign-in)